# How to check for Authorization Token in every Rest API in a rest controller without rewriting a method

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, maven, spring-restcontroller

I am building a Rest Controller in Spring Boot (Maven), and I want to be able to have my APIs have a `Authorization Bearer` token in which I can send a 401 response if the token is invalid but I do not want to manually check in every API that I create, Is there a way in which I can run a method that checks if the token is valid before actually running the API.

If the token is not valid I want to send a 401 instead of what the API was attended for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom filter (implementing `javax.servlet.Filter`), which would intercept every incoming request, where you can have your logic of checking if the request has an Authorization header.

```
@Component
public class AuthFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        if (req.getHeader("Authorization") != null){ //or replace with a further fine grained condition
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
            res.setStatus(401);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where would I add this component ? and thank you for the response !

Comment: @jaffer_syed You just need to create this custom filter class annotated with `@Component`. Spring boot will take care of wiring this. Nothing else required.